# Is there a way to connect mysql while a python application running?

Tags: python, mysql, connection

I'd like to make an python application and retrieve query results from mysql server.

So every time when an event happened, the application connect to mysql through mysqlclient like below

```
# retrieve query result from db
db=_mysql.connect(host="localhost",user="root",
                  passwd="password",db="db")
```

Is there a way not to try to connect every time but keep the connection?

Comment: What the event is? You can connect to database once at the beginning of the python script, and use it after that. If you re-run the python script when every event arrive, it must re-connect to the database.

Comment: Did you tried connection pooling?

Comment: @ElapsedSoul the event will be a message from MQ

Comment: @Sajidshaikh no i didn't. what is that? is there any documentation for connection pooling?

Comment: I read about it [here](https://pynative.com/python-database-connection-pooling-with-mysql/)

Comment: How do you schedule you python script to get the event from MQ. I think you need to run loop in python to get the message from MQ and store the data to the database.  You can connect to the database before the loop.

Comment: @ElapsedSoul That's right! I make a loop forever to pull message from MQ and then execute query. Thanks I will try that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```py
begin loop:
    get MQ msg
    db=_mysql.connect(host="localhost",user="root",
                  passwd="password",db="db")
    db.insert()
```

to

```py
db=_mysql.connect(host="localhost",user="root",
                  passwd="password",db="db")
begin loop:
    get MQ msg
    db.insert()
```

Comment: Additional remarks, the connection pool Sajidshaikh mentioned help you to manage the connection like parallel process and re-connection. If you care about the stability of the connection, you can use it.